# What are mappings and templates in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading ES documentation, but cannot understand in simple words what are mappings and templates. Please, clarify these terms.

Comment: the json schema of the document in an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this page : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

> Index templates define settings and mappings that you can
>   automatically apply when creating new indices. Elasticsearch applies
>   templates to new indices based on an index pattern that matches the
>   index name.

That means templates are composed of two metadata parts to describe your index :

1. The mapping part describes each document's indexation interface (structure + analysis options) : Expected fields with associated datatypes and the analyzers which will be applied on indexation.
2. The settings part, which describes characteristics / configurations on your indices. ie : How many shards will compose the index, how many replicas are needed, how often will the segments be merged, and so on ...

Note that templates are used to make new indices creation easier, be defining "default" structures and configurations